neo4j-java-driver(5.7.0) throws Cannot invoke "org.neo4j.driver.summary.InputPosition.line()" because "position" is null for Neo4j version: 5.19-aura
I am getting this error Cannot invoke "org.neo4j.driver.summary.InputPosition.line()" because "position" is nullfrom spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j(3.0.6)-> spring-data-neo4j(7.0.5)-> neo4j-java-driver(5.7.0)
below is the custom neo4j repository
public interface RoleRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Role, String> 
@Query("OPTIONAL MATCH shortestPath((pr:Role:`:#{literal(#module)}`{status:\"ACTIVE\",category:\"ADMIN\",type:$userRole})-[:MANAGES*..11]->(r:Role:`DQ`{status:\"ACTIVE\"}))\n"
                        + //
                        "WHERE r.type <> $userRole AND NOT r.type IN $excludedRoles\n" + //
                        "WITH collect(r) as adminRoles\n" + //
                        "OPTIONAL MATCH (ur:Role:`:#{literal(#module)}`{status:\"ACTIVE\",category:\"USER\"})\n"
                        + //
                        "WHERE ur.type <> $userRole AND NOT ur.type IN $excludedRoles\n" + //
                        "WITH adminRoles,collect(ur) as userRoles\n" + //
                        "WITH adminRoles+userRoles as roles\n" + //
                        "UNWIND roles as r\n" + //
                        "RETURN r{.code,.type}\n" + //
                        "SKIP $offset\n" + //
                        "LIMIT $limit")
        List<RoleProjection> fetchAllhierarchicallyMappable(@Param("userRole") String userRole,
                        @Param("module") String module,
                        @Param("excludedRoles") Set<String> excludedRoles,
                        @Param("offset") int offset, @Param("limit") int pageSize);

I have raise a similar issue on neo4j-java-driver-github-issue-1549.
This issue occurs for every query that uses COLLECT{} or collect().
Any ideas if am doing anything wrong with the collect queries ??
